# Getting system information using c#

Tags: c#

I have some problem (c#).

1. I can retrieve some mainboard info from win32-baseboard but when I want to get Model
   but an error accrued.
2. How can we get a list of installed software on windows (like xp).
3. How can we get a list of installed Peripheral device on Windows (with detail) (like scanner, webcam).
4. How to obtain **total** amount of ram (just) directly.

Comment: You can find all the answers to these questions already on SO.

Comment: Although i answered you should make more clear to your question that you indeed you use WMI and provide with a code sample.

Comment: I found the first problem's answer - "Model is blank"-tnx to e4rthdog

Answer (score 1):

Use WMI (I suspect you already using it):

1. Model is blank. Try `Manufacturer` property. Also get the `Product` property to get the model.
2. Installed software: Get the `Win32_Product` class.
3. Try `Win32_PnPSignedDriver` class and iterate through.
4. Use `Win32_ComputerSystem` class and get `TotalPhysicalMemory` property.

**Get WMIEXPLORER and play with it.** [LINK](http://wmie.codeplex.com/)

Sample for C#:

**If you require to connect to remote computer with credentials (strUsername and strPassword variables):**

```
private ManagementScope CreateNewManagementScope(string server) 
{ 
    string serverString = @"\\" + server + @"\root\cimv2"; 

    ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(serverString); 

    if (!chkUseCurrentUser.Checked) 
    { 
        ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions 
                          { 
                              Username = strUsername, 
                              Password = strPassword, 
                              Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate, 
                              Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy 
                          }; 
        scope.Options = options; 
    } 

    return scope; 
}
```

**Get the services:**

```
private void GetServicesForComputer(string computerName) 
{ 
    ManagementScope scope = CreateNewManagementScope(computerName); 

    SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("select * from Win32_Service"); 

    try 
    { 
        using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query)) 
        { 
            ManagementObjectCollection services = searcher.Get(); 

            List<string> serviceNames = 
                (from ManagementObject service in services select service["Caption"].ToString()).ToList(); 

            lstServices.DataSource = serviceNames; 
        } 
    } 
    catch (Exception exception) 
    { 
        lstServices.DataSource = null; 
        lstServices.Items.Clear(); 
        lblErrors.Text = exception.Message; 
        Console.WriteLine(Resources.MainForm_GetServicesForServer_Error__ + exception.Message); 
    } 
}
```

**Some screens from wmiexplorer:**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]